# private method `gets' called for ".." (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for this stupid question I am new in ruby.
 What is wrong in the code below that ends up with this error:

```
private method `gets' called for "file.txt":String (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the code:

```
def read_file(path)
 File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
    while line = path.gets
     puts line
    end 
 end 
end

def initialize
  read_file("file.txt")
end
```

Comment: -2, ouch, seems like an honest mistake to overlook, as a newbi...

Answer (score 2):

Replace `while line = path.gets` with `while line = file.gets`

Comment: This is correct. Should you actually want to call a private method on an object, in the future, you can use `path.send :gets` (but you want file here, for sure - it is the variable passed to the block as a result of the File.open command).

Comment: @Brad: But the thing is, the private `String#gets` (which is actually [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets)) reads from the standard input (more or less) so it is rarely the method you're looking for.

Comment: Right, I thought it might be worthwhile to describe the general use-pattern for accessing a private method, as he/she is a self-described newbi. Definitely a terrible idea to do it in this case, and, as you pointed out, most others (with that method, anyway) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying this:

```
path.gets
```

and `path` is a `String`. There is a [`gets` method in `Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets):

> **gets(sep=$/) → string**
>   **gets(limit) → string or nil**
>   **gets(sep,limit) → string or nil**
>
> Returns (and assigns to `$_`) the next line from the list of files in `ARGV` (or `$*`), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line.

[`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) includes `Kernel` via [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html) so the `gets` method noted above is also an instance method for `String`. But, `Kernel#gets` is private so `String#gets` is private and there's your error:

```
private method `gets' called for "file.txt":String (NoMethodError)
```

You want to be calling `gets` on `file` as noted elsewhere.

`Kernel#gets`, like many (all?) of the `Kernel` methods, is around so that you can treat `gets` like a plain function for quick'n'dirty one-liners and the like. The one-linerness of `Kernel#gets` is also why it does things to `$_`.

---

This answer is mostly background information so that you know what's going on. I'd recommend accepting [Hck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13304147/479863) since they're right and they got in first.

Comment: Great write up. Every time I see you, I learn something new and complex (I'm still playing with that erb). Just out of curiosity, how did you learn so much about the guts of Rails, are there any must-have resources for advanced concepts, or is it mostly from work/play?

Comment: @Brad: Thanks, I find that laying everything out helps me clarify my own thinking: if I can't explain it then I don't know it.  I've learned a lot of the interesting corners by answering SO questions (learning by teaching) and by diving head first into the source code when I need to. I've been around for awhile and I have a broad background so my main resource is experience. Let me know how that ERB stuff goes.